# How to add label in a SearchView outside of action bar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, searchview

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wOBS.png)

How do I add a label in a `SearchView`? At first I used an `ImageButton` and `Text` combination to achieve the display that I wanted. (See screenshot, 2nd row) I switched to a `SearchView` and I'm wondering how can I modify how it looks so it's the same as `ImageButton`/`Text` combination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a hint to the search view. See this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html#create-sc).

> Create a Searchable Configuration
>
> A searchable configuration defines how the SearchView behaves and is defined in a res/xml/searchable.xml file. At a minimum, a searchable configuration must contain an android:label attribute that has the same value as the android:label attribute of the  or  element in your Android manifest. However, we also recommend adding an android:hint attribute to give the user an idea of what to enter into the search box:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hint="@string/search_hint" />
```